# How to configure SQL Server database into TNSNAME.ora?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, dblink

I have created a DB Link into an Oracle Database, pointing to a SQL Server Database.
ODBC if properly configured for this SQL Server Database.
I have also installed Oracle Gateways for SQL Server, on the Oracle Database Server.

When I try to execute this SQL request on my Oracle database :

```
SELECT * FROM obbud@qualiactst

(qualiactst is my DBLink :
-- PROMPT CREATE DATABASE LINK qualiactst
CREATE DATABASE LINK qualiactst
  CONNECT TO iac IDENTIFIED BY ***** USING 'RIATST';

)
```

the error message is displayed as below :

```
ORA-12154: TNS : could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have configured the tnsname.ora file of my Oracle Database Server with this :

```
RIATST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = grensql2k12R2-1)(PORT = 14539))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = RIATST))
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

(but I don't really know if i have to add a non-oracle database into a tnsname.ora)

I don't understand what i have done wrong, and if some things are missing.

Can you help me ?
Thank you so much

Jeanne

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't set up listener onto the target host (grensql2k12R2-1) or don't configure HS initialization file.

Generally, try to follow [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/admin.htm#i1005982). There are too many details to check every of it in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

For communication with a heterogeneous MSSQL database. There are two options.

1) Use of specialized Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server. 
[Configuring Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OTGIS/configsql.htm#OTGIS900)
   2) Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC.
[Configuring Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OTGIS/configodbc.htm#OTGIS110)

Simple example configure Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server

ORACLE_HOME\dg4msql\admin\initdg4msql.ora

```
   HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=host_name:port_name//database_name
```

ORACLE_HOME\network\admin\listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER=

############# MS SQL ####################
   (SID_LIST=
      (SID_DESC= 
         (SID_NAME=dg4msql)
         (ORACLE_HOME=oracle_home_directory)
         (PROGRAM=dg4msql)
      )
   )
##########################################
```

Restart listener

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

ORACLE_HOME\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

```
connect_descriptor_mssql=
   (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=
         (PROTOCOL=TCP)
         (HOST=host_name_oracle_gateway_host)
         (PORT=port_number_listener_1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=
         (SID=dg4msql))
      (HS=OK))



SQL> CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK name_dblink CONNECT TO "user" IDENTIFIED BY "password" USING 'connect_descriptor_mssql';
 SQL> SELECT * FROM DUAL@dblink;
```

Example from production server Oracle 11.2.0.4

/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dg4msql/admin/inittch7.ora

```
   HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=[10.89.250.87]:1433/
```

/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dg4msql/admin/inittch7.ora

```
 HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=[10.89.250.88]:1433/
```

/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1525))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.89.251.242)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ssps)
        (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (SID_NAME = ssps)
    )
     (SID_DESC=
        (SID_NAME=tch8)
        (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (PROGRAM=dg4msql)
          )
    (SID_DESC=
         (SID_NAME=tch7)
         (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
         (PROGRAM=dg4msql)
         )

  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/oracle/database
```

/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
SSPS_1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.89.251.242)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ssps)
    )
  )



atch7 =
  (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= 10.89.251.242)(PORT=1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=tch7))
      (HS=OK)
    )


atch8 =
  (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.89.251.242)(PORT=1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=tch8))
      (HS=OK)
    )




 CREATE DATABASE LINK ATCH7.GIFT.KRSK.MPS
      CONNECT TO "asuzm_link" IDENTIFIED BY <ENTER USER PASSWORD HERE>
      USING 'atch7'
    /

CREATE DATABASE LINK ATCH8.GIFT.KRSK.MPS
  CONNECT TO "asuzm_link" IDENTIFIED BY <ENTER USER PASSWORD HERE>
  USING 'atch8'
/
```